# Prove that if x is irrational, then sqrt(x) is irrational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

[image]

I believe the contrapositive method should be correct but i get,

The contrapositive of this statement should be,

(If $\sqrt{x}$ is rational, then $x$ is rational)

Then I end up with $x=\frac{m^2}{n^2}$ for $m,n$ to be integers and $n$ does not equal 0.

Is it careless to be done with the proof since we are saying that $x=\frac{m^2}{n^2}$ is a rational number therefore the contrapositive is true, therefore the original statement is also true?

Comment: Is this actually supposed to be a question with a "correct" answer?

Comment: No, that proof is correct.

Comment: yeah there is suppose to be a correct answer

Comment: @ZachEffman I meant that there's no "right" way of going about proving it. Each one of those proof methods would be viable (although one may be more clean or efficient than another).

Comment: oh yeah all three methods can be used to prove it, just whether the proof is correct or not

Comment: @nignog I agree, I was responding to the question of is the OP's proof careless.

Answer (score 1):

$[p\implies q]\iff [\neg q\implies\neg p]$

If you prove the contrapositive of a statement, that completes the proof of the statement, because a statement is true if and only if its contrapositive is true (draw a truth table and verify this).

---

The Proof by Contradiction also can be used:
Let $x$ is irrational and assume $\sqrt x$ is rational. Then you can arrive at a contradiction to $x$ is irrational.

Comment: You can always use all three types of proofs. Usually you just need to use LEM ($p \vee \neg p$) somewhere in the direct proof.

Comment: Both the OP's proof and the answer here are wrong. Counterexample: let $x = -\sqrt{2}$, then $\sqrt{x}$ is an imaginary number. Therefore, not rational!

Comment: @user13985 This is not a counterexample to the statement here. Read the assumptions and conclusion carefully.